# Is there a good set of ffmpeg presets to target multiple platforms available anywere?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding

I'm working on a web app that would let users upload a video.

The user's video should then be played on apps on a few platforms:

- web, via flash
- iOS native player
- Android phones - hopefully all players, even low-end devices

I plan to do the encoding with `ffmpeg` which has this very cool `preset` feature.

I'm sure I'm not the only one to find this out, but when I Google `ffmpeg encode for iPhone`, I get as many different parameter sets on people's blogs as results.

Furthermore, people sometimes use parameters which are not even documented.

Since `ffmpeg` supports these presets, I can't believe we don't have a "preset database" somewhere which has such presets as `iPhone_low_quality`, `Android_low_end_device_low_quality`, etc.

Am I just failing to find it?